# How to allow users to write jetpack custom post types?

Tags: plugin-jetpack

I am using latest version of WordPress and jetpack. I have used **custom post type ui** plugin for custom post type which allow user to write custom posts, but this is not supporting **jetpack publicize** feature.So i have to use jetpack post type for **publicize** support.But jetpack post types don't allow users to write. Can i give users capability to write jetpack post types ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use Jetpack Post Types feature for that. Just use the following code to enable Jetpack Plublicize for any custom post type of your theme/plugin. Place it in `functions.php`:

```
/**
 * Enable Jetpack Publicize Support for CPT
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
function wpse20150812_jetpack_publicize_support() {
    add_post_type_support( 'mycpt', 'publicize' );
}
add_action('init', 'wpse20150812_jetpack_publicize_support');
```

Replace the `mycpt` with your registered Custom Post Type.

**Reference:** [jetpack.me - Support](https://jetpack.me/support/publicize/#custom-post-types)

Comment: Thank's Mayeenul. That's work.I want another help.My custom post type is in bengali language.Can i add subscription option for bengali posts(custom post type)?.Really, i want to add different subscription option for posts and custom posts type. Do you know how to do this ? i am using jetpack subscriber.

Comment: #1. Please don't mix multiple question in a single one. #2. WPSE is not the right place for asking 3rd party plugin specific questions (Read the [FAQ] please). Better ask the question in Jetpack support forum.